# jQuery UI Autocomplete widget search configuration not working with spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

- I am using jquery ui autocomplete in which we are showing cities matching starts with the term.
- If i type **LOND** showing all cities starting with 'LOND'
- Now i am trying to search **New YO** (going to search NEW YORK) autocomplete match is not happening. Below is my autocomplete code. Please help

> ```
> var term = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term)
> , startsWithMatcher =new RegExp("\\b" + term, "i")
> , startsWith = $.grep(cities, function(value) {
> return startsWithMatcher.test(value.aircode || value.airport_name || value.value || value.airport_name || value.keyword);
> })
> , containsMatcher =  new RegExp("^" + term, "i")
> , contains = $.grep(cities, function (value) {
> return $.inArray(value, startsWith) < 0 && 
> containsMatcher.test(value.value || value.id || value.aircode || value.airport_name || value.keyword);
> });
>
> response(startsWith.concat(contains).slice(0, limit));
> ```

Comment: Please create a working demo of your code on jsfiddle or codepen